# How can I retrive URL from xml by Node.js?

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js, web-scraping

I am working on web scraping. Currently I want to scrap a website. I have got an xml file link from robots.txt file. Now I want to read all url from that xml. But cant do this. Can anyone help me to figure it out ?

XML format :

```
<urlset>
    <url>
       <loc>http://www.xxxx.com/</loc>
       <changefreq>test</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url>
       <loc>http://www.xxxx.com/</loc>
       <changefreq>test</changefreq>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

Here is my code :

```
        var fs = require('fs')
          , flow = require('xml-flow')
          , inFile = fs.createReadStream(xml_file_url)
          , xmlStream = flow(inFile)
        ;

        xmlStream.on('tag:urlset', function(err,url) {
            if(err)
                return console.log(err);
          console.log(url);
          res.send('Check your console!')

        });
```

I want all the url from loc & push them on an array. How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A suggestion. If you know how to work with jQuery to traversing nodes, take a look at https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select tag:loc and every tag push to array:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    flow = require('xml-flow'),
    http = require('http');

var file = fs.createWriteStream('site.xml');

http.get('http://ajkerdeal.com/sitemap.xml', function(res) {
    res.on('data', function(data) {
        file.write(data);
    }).on('end', function() {
        file.end();

        var inFile = fs.createReadStream("site.xml"),
            xmlStream = flow(inFile);

        var array = [];
        xmlStream.on('tag:loc', function(url) {
            array.push(url.$text);
        });

        xmlStream.on('end', function(url) {
            console.log(array);

        });
    })
})
```

Comment: I am trying to read http://www.ajkerdeal.com/sitemap.xml file. But I am getting error. 
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: ENOENT, open 'http://www.ajkerdeal.com/sitemap.xml'
    at Error (native)

Comment: I updated my answer. You should read more about FS and creating stream. You can only use FS to local file system. I this case you need download file from http and then processed locally